# Aspose epub convert table to image gives different colours

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I have the following problem: while converting a .doc document that contains some tables Aspose changes their colour. So when you see the image of that table in the already formed .epub document it is different from the one you receive by clicking on this image.

It looks something like that:

The image view:
[image: The image view]

The table view: 
[image: The table view]

Could anyone please give an idea about what could cause this problem?

EDIT:

The thing is that the tables are actually converted to images. So the new epub contains the images instead of tables.

Comment: Try the latest release, if you are using an old version. If still you have problems, can you post the link to the sample Word document?

Comment: I'm using the last release. Here is the document - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B21cdIrPljsTdzhhQ1Q3VGY0NFk/edit

Comment: Tried the conversion with Aspose.Words 13.6, the table colors are same as the source Word document. This is the link to epub https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D3B2D40126456182!3021&authkey=!AF_9qRam1B9fuPo. I opened the epub in Adobe Digital Editions latest version

Comment: It might be an issue with the EPUB viewer. Which app are you using to open EPUB document?

Comment: I'm using Calibre E-book viewer.

Comment: I've just tried with the Adobe Digital Editions and the result is still the same. The colours are different.

Comment: Just checking again, if you were able to solve the issue. I have used only 2 lines of source code to convert from docx to epub. May be the formatting is lost during editing or any other thing. I have sent you the complete VS 2012 project with binaries and data files. Please check at your end. If it does not work, post the source code too.

Comment: @Saqib Thank you, Sir. I've already found the problem. I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: @user, I know this is a very old question, but do you happen to recall what the problem was and/or how you found the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @BryanMatthews Oh well, 2+ years passed.. :) 
As I slightly playback this in my head, that was our bad. We had a not-really-visible hack that used to intercept some of our documents and in order to make them compliant with some e-books, we did changes to the actual image, that resulted in the error above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for getting back to me :)